# Make two couroutines run on the background in python

Tags: python, multithreading, coroutine

I have two coroutines:

- one to keep a connection to a server alive sending a heartbeat.
- the other is listening to any message that comes back from the server.

What I would like is to have the two coroutines run in the background in a thread.

This is what I have tried but I fail in printing the messages from the server.

```
import threading
import time
import asyncio

async def heartbeat():
   while True:
       await client.websok.send_message('\n')
       time.sleep(30)

async def listen():
   while True:
       msg = await client.websok.receive_message()
       print(msg)

def background_loop():
   loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
   asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
   tasks = [heartbeat(),listen()]
   loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))


#Main code

t = threading.Thread(target=background_loop)
client = #create API connection

t.start()
```

Any input is more than welcome. Thanks for your help

Comment: If you set the thread to daemon but don’t actually do anything else, there is nothing to keep your program alive.

Comment: Thanks. I removed it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an [mre]. Otherwise, people are left guessing what to fill into the blanks. Since this covers *at least* three topics (threads, asyncio, websockets) it would be prudent to follow the MRE guidelines and eliminate as many of them as possible. For example, do you have the same problem when trying to print hardcoded messages without the use of a websocket? Do you have the same problem when running the coroutines in the main thread?

Comment: `time.sleep()` literally blocks thread, you should've use `await asyncio.sleep()` instead

Answer (score 1):

To run two coroutines or more concurrently you would use `asyncio.gather`:

```py
import asyncio


async def heartbeat():
    while True:
        await client.websok.send_message("\n")
        await asyncio.sleep(30)


async def listen():
    while True:
        msg = await client.websok.receive_message()
        print(msg)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(heartbeat(), listen())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

They already "run in the background", you do not need a thread here. If you need to run `main` concurrently with another coroutine, just use `asyncio.gather` again.

If you really need to schedule a coroutine from a different thread than the one where the AsyncIO event loop is running, then you should use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

Do not use `time.sleep` but `asyncio.sleep`, since the former will block the event loop from running other coroutines. Also, you never joined the thread (with the `join` method), thus you never awaited its completion.